# Extract certain information from MySQL entry

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains information about music. One of the names of a column is called `path`. In the path column there is text that looks like `\\Buffalo\music\On Demand\M418+Rend+Misty Edwards+04.0+04.0+M+12_31_2000+12_31_2099+0+03_56_0+.mp3`. Is there a way in PHP to echo just the artist and just the title? So if were to have a web page I could show Title: TITLE-HERE Artist: ARTIST-HERE. The title is immediately after the first + and the artist is immediately after the second +. So in this case the title is Rend and the artist is Misty Edwards. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Obligatory mention of the fact that if you have control over how this data is stored, you should pull this information out of the "path" at storage time and save them in the appropriate fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not especially robust:

```
// \\Buffalo\music\On Demand\M418+Rend+Misty Edwards+04.0+04.0+M+12_31_2000+12_31_2099+0+03_56_0+.mp3

list( , $title, $artist) = explode ("+", $path);
```

It'll fail if you have a `+` in the first part of the string, but should work fine otherwise.

Comment: That's a very neat way of doing it - I've not seen it done that way in PHP before.